# Construction of DecisionTree in data mining

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

What should be done if *Information Gain* exceeds 1?

Comment: You will need to describe a specific problem and provide a lot more context and information in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: -5/18log(5/18)-5/18log(5/18)-4/18log(4/18)-4/18log(4/18) the log is of base 2 not base 10.The answer of the above calculation is exceeding above 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information gain is always less than 1.

If it is larger than 1, then you have made a programming error.